# the request sent is not recognized by the sprig controller when parameters are sent as RequestBody and RequestParam

Tags: java, angularjs, spring-mvc

I am working on spring application with angularjs.
I am trying to send JSON object as a RequestBody and a RequestParam information from angularjs to spring controller, but the spring controller
is not recognizing the request sent from angularjs.

js:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    var myApp = angular.module('app');
    myApp.controller('fileWithJSONController', function ($scope, fileUploadService) {

        $scope.uploadFile = function () {
            var file = $scope.myFile;
            var uploadUrl = myApplnURL + '/showInfo/getInformationTest';", //Url of web service
             $scope.emailData = [
                    {   'from':$scope.fromEmail,
                        'ccEmail': $scope.ccEmail,
                        'subject': $scope.subject,
                        'message':$scope.message,
                    }
              ];
               var fd=new FormData();
                angular.forEach($scope.files,function(file){
                       fd.append('file',file);
                  });
            promise = fileWithJSONService.sendInformation(fd, $scope.emailData, uploadUrl);

            promise.then(function (response) {
                $scope.serverResponse = response;
            }, function () {
                $scope.serverResponse = 'An error has occurred';
            })
        };
    });

})();

(function () {
    'use strict';
    var myApp = angular.module('app');
    myApp.service('fileWithJSONService', function ($http, $q) {

        this.sendInformation = function (fd, emailData, uploadUrl) {

            var deffered = $q.defer();
            $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, emailData, {
                transformRequest: angular.identity,
                headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}

            }).success(function (response) {
                deffered.resolve(response);

            }).error(function (response) {
                deffered.reject(response);
            });

            return deffered.promise;
        }
    });
})();
```

Spring controller:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/getInformationTest", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = {"content-type=multipart/form-data"})
    public
    @ResponseBody
    String sendInformationTest(@RequestParam("file") List<MultipartFile> multiPartFileList,@RequestBody("emailData") EmailDataDTO emailDataDTO){                         
         System.out.println("In spring controller");
         System.out.println("single file " +multiPartFileList.size());
    }
```

--EDITED--

PS: The path to the spring controller is correct, because when i pass only one argument from angularjs to spring controller then it is hitting the spring controller. Sample code below:

js:

```
 ....
 $http.post(uploadUrl, fd , {
                    transformRequest: angular.identity,
                    headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}

                })...
```

spring controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getInformationTest", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = {"content-type=multipart/form-data"})
    public
    @ResponseBody
    String sendInformationTest(@RequestParam("file") List<MultipartFile> multiPartFileList){                         
         System.out.println("In spring controller");
         System.out.println("single file " +multiPartFileList.size());
    }
```

o/p:

```
In spring controller
single File 2
```

----EDITED---
I tried to change the RequestBody to RequestParam as shown in below 2 ways but both the ways are not hitting the spring controller.

First trial:
js:

```
 ....
 $http.post(uploadUrl, fd ,emailData, {
                    transformRequest: angular.identity,
                    headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}

                })...
```

spring controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getInformationTest", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = {"content-type=multipart/form-data"})
    public
    @ResponseBody
    String sendInformationTest(@RequestParam("file") List<MultipartFile> multiPartFileList,@RequestParam("emailData") List<EmailDataDTO> emailData){                         
         System.out.println("In spring controller");
      }
```

Trial2:
js:

```
..
  $scope.emailData = [
                        {   'from':$scope.fromEmail,
                            'ccEmail': $scope.ccEmail,
                            'subject': $scope.subject,
                            'message':$scope.message,
                        }
                  ];
                   var fd=new FormData();
                     fd.append("emailData",$scope.emailData);
                    angular.forEach($scope.files,function(file){
                           fd.append('file',file);
                      });
                promise = fileWithJSONService.sendInformation(fd, $scope.emailData, uploadUrl);
 ....
  ....//service call
     $http.post(uploadUrl, fd , {
                        transformRequest: angular.identity,
                        headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}

                    })...
```

--EDITED---
I have CommonsMultipartResolver configured in servlet.xml

```
<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
        <property name="maxUploadSize" value="10000000"/>
    </bean>
```

Comment: What is the error

Comment: It is not showing any error, but not hitting the spring controller.

Comment: So, the API path is wrong?

Comment: @NiVeR - Please see the edited section in the post above.. I tried passing only one argument from js to spring controller and the sprig controller is invoked. Issue occurs only when i'm trying to pass two arguments from js to spring controller.

Comment: Change the `@RequestBody` to `@RequestParam`.

Comment: @NiVeR - I tried two different ways to pass it as RequestParam which i have added in the edited section of the post above..both of the ways are not working and the spring controller is not invoked..Do i need to change the header information in the spring controller?

Comment: Yes, I was referring to that. Use @RequestParam for everthing in the body.

Comment: Yes i have usede @RequestParam as shown in FirstTrial and Trial2 of edited section in above post but still it is not hitting the spring controller..

Comment: In the JS code the URL is `/showInfo/getInformationTest`, but I don't see `/showInfo` on the Spring side? Is it in RequestMapping of the Controller?  
Also, are you uploading multiple files at once or one at a time? I'm not sure `List<MultipartFile>` actually works with Spring - did you try with only one file (RequestParam)?  
In addition, I recently implemented something similar and ended up using [ng-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload) to handle the upload.

Comment: What is the error code you are getting?

Comment: @Supun Dharmarathne - It is not showing any error either on browser console or server console.. it is unable to hit the spring controller. Any inputs are helpful..

Comment: @RikH - Yes /showInfo is the RequestMapping of the controller. I tried uploading single file as well as multiple files with my above code and it is working file. Initially i tried using ng-file-upload but ended with errors so using commons-fileupload.jar..

Comment: Is Spring security enabled in your project?

Answer (score 0):

In server if you sending data in the form of JSON then change `headers = {"content-type=multipart/form-data"}` to  `headers = {"content-type=application/json"}`
and check CORS enabled or not.
Change your headers from front end headers: {'Content-Type': undefined} to 
headers: {'Content-Type': "content-type=multipart/form-data"}

Comment: I just checked it, it is still not hitting the spring controller when i changed from multipart/form-data too application/json. And one thing i would like to say is i need to send files information as well as JSON object to the spring controller and header for both are totally different, any inputs?

Comment: install POSTMAN application test webservice alone @nan

Comment: Configure MultipartResolver and from the front end you should submit it as formData

Comment: I have CommonsMultipartResolver configured in my servlet.xml file.Please see the edited section of the above post.How to submit it as formData?

Comment: headers: {'Content-Type': undefined} why you set headers undefined from front end

Comment: To pass the attached files information i need to set headers: {'Content-Type': undefined} .If you see the js code i'm appending the attached files information and passing the details (fd) to the spring controller..I need to pass files information as well as JSON object from js to the spring controller which is not allowing and reason could be the headers...but is there any other way to resolve this issue?

Comment: header should match both from front end and server.

Comment: Is there any way to send files information for which the header should be headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}  and JSON object for which the header should be header:{"content-type=application/json"} from frontend to the server??